# Stereochemistry of meso compounds

Tags: stereochemistry

I got tripped up by this question; I thought these were all enantiomers when in fact they were all meso compounds.

How can one prevent this from happening?

[image]

How does one rotate the Fischer projection, for example, in the first problem; I understand that one has to hold one group in place, but then what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rotate on a single bond in a Fischer Projection, all 3 groups move in the same direction. $\frac {1} {2\ \ \ 3} \rightarrow \frac {2} {3\ \ \ 1}$. See [this page](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Organic_Chemistry/Chirality/Meso_Compounds) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Exchanging two groups in fischer projection changes it to its enantiomer and further exchange reverts it back.After exchanging as follows gives meso compound with internal plane of symmetry:

> Note that these are for the compunds on the left. 
>   Do similiarly for others on right

a) $\ce{CH3<->H}$ THEN $\ce{H<->OH}$

b)Rotate nearer $C$ by $\pi/3$ rad. anticlock wise.

c)Imagine rotation about $C_2-C_3$ by $\pi$ rad., the $OH$ in the right back of the plane comes in front projecting out towards us hanging down and thus we have a vertical plane of symmetry.